# ngx-datatable date sorting by Year ANGULAR 8

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I have the following situation in ngx-datatable from angular. When you click on a column, it does the sorting in alphabetical order and in the case of the date it is taking by day and not by year. I believe it is because the American format is the first year. (2019-12-03 and not as in brasil 03-12-2019). Would anyone know how to resolve this impasse? It follows below.

[image]

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-macroareas',
    templateUrl: './macroareas.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./macroareas.component.scss']
})
export class MacroareasComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Macroáreas';
    public macroarea = [];
    loadingIndicator = true;
    reorderable = true;
    public right_side_bar: boolean;

    columns = [
        { prop: 'id' },
        { prop: 'macroarea', name: 'Macroárea' },
        { prop: 'data_formatada', name: 'Data de cadastro' },
    ];

}
```

And how do I display the data in my macroareas.component.html

```html
       <div class="card-body custom-datatable">
                    <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap pointer" [rows]="macroarea" [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
                        [columns]="columns" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="40" [summaryPosition]="'bottom'"
                        [footerHeight]="40" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [reorderable]="reorderable" 
                        [selectionType]="SelectionType.single" [limit]="10" (select)="open(mymodalEdit, $event)"
                        (activate)="onLoadMacroaresDatas($event)">
                    </ngx-datatable>
                </div>
```

Would anyone know the solution to such a problem in ngx-datatable?

Comment: check this:
https://therichpost.com/angular-7-datatables-working-example/

Comment: this post don´t say anything about that question.